# SQL query to find closest distance between coordinates is running very slowly

Tags: mysql, sql, coordinates, geospatial

I have the following query which does indeed work. It takes in a hard set Latitude and Longitude and finds the closest set of coordinates, along with it's postal code.

What I'm having trouble with is the speed of the query. It's currently taking 3.8 seconds to run and I have 9000 separate coordinates to check.

Any advice on how to speed this up would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT pcds, ROUND(MIN(distance), 4) AS distance FROM
(SELECT `postcode`.`pcds`,(
    6371 * acos (
      cos ( radians('51.4932392') )
      * cos( radians( `postcode`.`lat` ) )
      * cos( radians( `postcode`.`lng` ) - radians('-0.0846429') )
      + sin ( radians('51.4932392') )
      * sin( radians( `postcode`.`lat` ) )
    )
) AS distance
FROM postcode
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 1
) AS First
```

Comment: Divide your field to squares not over 10-20 points per square. Perform pre-filtering by "the point is in the same or adjacent square" using direct non-calculational compare, then check the distances for filtered points only. Pre-calculate `sin/cos ( radians('51.4932392') )` and use their values instead of expressions. Multiply by 6371 in output, not in subquery.

Comment: Use a proper GIS package:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-types.html.